# React - How To Compare Props Between Separate Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

How can I compare if the props between two separate components have the same value?

1- Is what I'm seeking doable?

2- If not, how else could I accomplish the ask below:

**The story:**

- I have an array of car objects.
  Each car's name is displayed as `<li />` on a `<CarList />` component.
  Upon click on each `<li/>` the car's color is revealed
- I have a `<Question />` component that renders: "What car is (random color here)"?

**UI change:** 
How could I write a method that:

- Checks if the props.color of `<CarList />` === the props.color of `<Question />`
- Then it fires a UI change such as:
- **onClick**: `If` the car's color matches the question's color: change the `<li />` to green (ie: background-color), `else` change it to red.

I'm struggling (wondering if it's possible) to compare props from different components + writing a method that checks and executes the UI change above.

This is the code reflecting the explanation above: Also here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxo004r9x5)

```
// Garage
export default class Garage extends Component {
  state = {
    cars: [
      { name: "Ferrari", color: "red", id: 1 },
      { name: "Porsche", color: "black", id: 2 },
      { name: "lamborghini", color: "green", id: 3 },
      { name: "McLaren", color: "silver", id: 4 },
      { name: "Tesla", color: "yellow", id: 5 }
    ]
  };

  handleShuffle = () => {
    this.setState({
      cars: [...this.state.cars.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)]
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { cars } = this.state;
    const car = cars.map(car => (
      <CarList key={car.id} make={car.name} color={car.color} />
    ));

    const guess = cars
      .slice(2, 3)
      .map(car => <Question key={car.id} color={car.color} />);
    return (
      <>
        <div>{guess}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleShuffle}>load color</button>
        <ul>{car}</ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}

// CarList
class CarList extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
    console.log(this.props);
    // check for props equality here

    //desired result for <li /> would be
    // className={ correctColor ? 'green' : 'red'}
  };

  render() {
    console.log("car color props:", this.props.color);
    const { make, color } = this.props;
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleShow}>
        {make}
        <span className={show ? "show" : "hide"}>{color}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

// Question
const Question = ({ color }) =>
  console.log("question color prop:", color) || <h1>What car is {color}</h1>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the correct color to the `CarList` component or the flag whether the `CarList` is a correct one. Check my sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/92xnwpyq6p

Basically we can add `isCorrect` prop to `CarList` which has value of `correctCar.color === car.color` and we use it to determine whether we should render it green or red.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and code example. Ideally red or green only triggers upon clicking. Prior to it, it should stay in `black`. Would/Should I massage this logic on `className={.....}`?

Comment: you can use empty string in that case. I think I also use it in my sandbox. Check it out

Comment: Apologies for my confusion. Empty string, how so? I don't see it in your sandbox

Comment: check my getColor() function

Comment: your fork (posted on the answer) doesn't seem to have a `getColor()`. Also, what is the thought process behind the `correctIndex` logic that you implemented? I'd like to understand it.

Comment: Garage.js line 62

correctIndex: Math.random() returns a random number between 0 and 1. I multiply it by the length of cars minus 1, means if the length is 5, the random number would be a random number between 0 and 4. Since I want an integer, I call Math.floor.

Comment: That makes sense thank you! Ok to finalize, what is the suggestion/solution to keep the color as black and only change to green/red upon click?  Garage.js Line 62 of the fork is `render() {` , maybe you're looking at a diff version that wasn't shared on the answer above.

Comment: oh I forgot to hit save, you should be able to see it now

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks again for your time. I'll spend the rest of my evening studying your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Theres many ways to do this but the simplest is to send the color in the question down to the car component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/my4wmn427x

Comment: Thank you! So with this approach where/how `<Question/>` becomes aware of the `questionColor` sent down to  `<CarList />`?

Comment: <Question> is not aware it's color is being sent to <CarList>. In this approach the garage is aware of both colors and chooses to additionally send down the question color to <CarList> so that each car can do a comparison against its own car color :)